# Create Connection String during installation

Tags: vb.net

I have a Windows Forms application. I want to create a setup file for this application. I used Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 12.

I want this setup to work in every new environment.

So, how do I make this connection string dynamic? Can I create a connection string after installation and make it available for every form to access, like in my local machine?

Any kind of source code, video links, explanations or examples will be a great help for me.

Comment: Are you expecting each installation to have it's own local copy of SQL running?

Comment: James Thorpe: Yes.

Comment: if, as you state, each machine has a local copy of SQL running which the app must connect to, then the connection string can probably be the same for all of them, specifying "localhost". Unless you need to vary username/password, or some other setting?

Comment: ADyson: Can you provide me some links or the codes. I am not providing any passwords. I used Windows Authentication.

Comment: My plan is to provide a form that takes the server and database name when they installs the app for the first time and generate the connection string. Is it a good approach? I am not a pro in this.

Comment: you said in your comment above that each machine where the app is deployed has SQL server running locally, yes? So if you specify "localhost" as the hostname in the default connection string (which you can provide via an app.config file deployed with your application), that will point to the SQL on the local machine in every case, no need to change it.

Comment: Okay, that sounds easy,But if I want to access a central database then?

Comment: well, then it's always the same database, so that can be fixed too. Unless, you are deploying this to multiple different customers? In that case, you should build something into the installer which will allow the admin who is installing the package to specify the hostname at install time. That would then set the value in your config file. I'm pretty sure that's possible, but I don't know how. I don't know if you're more likely to get an answer to that on here or on the ServerFault site.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to search on the machine for instances of the SQL server, and then in every instance search for the databases. You could setup some logic for example if only one instance is found, and on this instance only database with specific name exists then use this database, but if two or more instances are found, or different database name then preferred is found, show window to user where he can choose the right one.

To find Database instance you could use following method:

```
private static DataRowCollection SQLDataServers()
{
   System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
   DataTable dt = instance.GetDataSources();
   if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
   {
       return dt.Rows;
   }
   throw new Exception("No SQL Instance Found");
}
```

To find tables in the database you can use following method:

```
private static List<string> GetDatabases(string conString)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from sys.databases", con))
        {
            using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
   }
   return list;
}
```

To generate connection string you can use [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProductivityTools.ConnectionString/) or following methods:

```
public static string GetSqlDataSourceConnectionString(string dataSource)
{
    return GetSQLDataSource(dataSource).ToString();
}


private static SqlConnectionStringBuilder GetSQLDataSource(string dataSource)
{
    var r = GetDataSource(dataSource).AddIntegratedSecurity();
    return r;
}

private static SqlConnectionStringBuilder GetDataSource(string dataSource)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new 
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
    return sqlBuilder;
}

private static SqlConnectionStringBuilder AddIntegratedSecurity(this SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder)
{
    connectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    return connectionStringBuilder;
}
```

The method which connects all this elements can be as following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var servers=SQLDataServers();
    foreach (DataRow item in servers)
    {
        string serverName = string.Format($"{item.ItemArray[0].ToString()}\\{item.ItemArray[1].ToString()}");
        var connectionString = GetSqlDataSourceConnectionString(serverName);
        var listOfDB=GetDatabases(connectionString);
     }
}
```